# Parsing BLE Adversitement Packages in Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to read data from a BLE transmitter connected to a scale that measures in kilograms, I am able to read data, and it varies when I change the weight on the scale, but I am not able to extract the weight in kilograms

The BLE B24 technical sheet is:
https://www.mantracourt.com/userfiles/documents/b24_telemetry_technical_manual.pdf

I´m trying to use the Manufacturer Specific Data section of page 4 and Example in page 14

I have tried with several parsers that I have seen on the forum but I can't get anything...

EDITED NEW CODE AND OUTPUT
The Activity code is:

```
public class PruebaConexion18_12_2023Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private Handler mHandler;
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
private BluetoothLeScanner mLEScanner;
private ScanSettings settings;
private List<ScanFilter> filters;
private BluetoothGatt mGatt;
TextView bLTextView;
Button startButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prueba_conexion18_12_2023);

    bLTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bLTextView);
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startReceivingAdversitement();

        }
    });
    mHandler = new Handler();
}

private void startReceivingAdversitement() {
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    } else {
        mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
          .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
          .build();
        filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }
}
private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                    mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);

            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);
        mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
    } else {
        mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
    }
}

StringBuilder sBMapa = new StringBuilder();



private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        Log.e("callbackType", "MAX " + String.valueOf(callbackType));
        Log.e("result", "MAX " + result.toString());
        BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
        if(null!=btDevice.getName()){
            if(btDevice.getName().equals("B24")){
             SparseArray<byte[]> manufData = result.getScanRecord().getManufacturerSpecificData();
                byte[] manufDatakeyAt0 = manufData.get(manufData.keyAt(0));
                ParseRecordStackMiPregunta(manufDatakeyAt0);
                String s =  bytesToHex(manufDatakeyAt0);
                sBMap.append(s);
                sBMap.append("\n");
                float manufDataFloat = ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(manufDatakeyAt0, 9, 13)).getFloat();
                sBMap.append(manufDataFloat);
                sBMap.append("\n");
                updateScreen();
                Log.e("ScanResult - Results", "MAX " + result.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        for (ScanResult sr : results) {
            Log.e("ScanResult - Results", "MAX " + sr.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        Log.e("Scan Failed", "MAX " + "Error Code: " + errorCode);
    }
};



public void updateScreen(){
    try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    bLTextView.setText(sBMapa.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

And the NEW data received from de device:

```
    0166786C5FDDF1D260700D0A27

0166786C5FDD0EE73C700D0A27
```

Using @petzval 's method never stops in the bucle

Edit2:
THANKS to @Risto now I have the data: DDF1F084 but it is encrypted, in page 14 the say that i have to do an XOR opeartion

in the example that they show convert

Encoded: 0x5B 0x51 0x96 0x11 -> 0x5B519611

Unencoded: 0x40 0x22 0x8F 0x5C -> 0x40228F5C ->2.54

Using this web the conversion
[https://gregstoll.com/~gregstoll/floattohex/](https://gregstoll.com/%7Egregstoll/floattohex/)

```
from 0x40228f5c to 2.54 is correct
 ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[]{0x40,0x22, (byte) 0x8F,0x5C}).getFloat(); returns 2.54 too

0x
```

5B519611 gives me 5.89933e+16

the line that i don´t understand now from page 14 in documentation is:

```
     Seed     PIN
0x40 0x2F XOR 0x34 = 0x1B 0x5B
0x22 0x41 XOR 0x32 = 0x73 0x51
0x8F 0x21 XOR 0x38 = 0x19 0x96
0x5C 0x7A XOR 0x37 = 0x4D 0x11
```

The View PIN is 0000

I think that i have to convert DDF1F084 to Hex Array again and do an XOR operation, but i dont know how to do it...

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Your data is turned into unreadable rubbish by several improper function calls in your source code. This means that nobody will be able to help you understand the data of your scale correctly.

Comment: @Risto wich one?

Comment: As the Bluetooth Advertisement isn't string data, you'll need to replace `sBMapa.toString()` with something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/java-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string

Comment: Your source code seems fishy and the example data looks wrong. According to the specification you linked, the measurement you are scanning for measures pressure (Units: 0x5F), and the measurement is at index 5, not 9. And the Status value (0x6C) indicates several problems (Digital Input Active Flag, Low battery warning flag,Input is out of sensitivity or display range, A tare value has been applied)

Comment: @ Risto, looking for the units table(page 21), the one that i want is 0x2D mass kilograms. I´m trying to use the Manufacturer Specific Data section of page 4 and Example in page 14

Comment: Based on the data you have entered here, I would say that the length of the "Payload" of the "Manufacturer Specific Data" is already correct and the first structural element also looks right. But then the data becomes strange. Either you are looking at the wrong data or your source code is changing it (e.g. what does `ParseRecordStackMiPregunta()` do?). This is how I would interpret one of your example datagrams, for example:

Comment: `0166786C5FDDF1F084700D0A27`, Format ID: `01`, Data Tag: `6678`, Status: `6C`, Units: `5F`, Data: `DDF1F084`, Data Tag: `700D`, Data Tag: `0A27`

Comment: @Risto i had edited with your help, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
        int n,len,getout;
        byte[] rec;
   
        rec = result.getScanRecord().getBytes();
        len = rec.length;
        n = 0;
        getout = 0;
        while(n < len-2 && rec[n] > 0 && getout == 0)
          {
          // rec[n] is length of item
          if(rec[n] > 1 && rec[n+1] == 0xFF)
            {  // manuf data
            // IEEE 4-byte float data is rec[n+9],rec[n+10],rec[n+11],rec[n+12]
            // Easy in C, but I don't know how to persuade Java that this
            // is a float type variable, but someone will
            getout = 1;
            }
          else
            n += rec[n] + 1;
          }
```